# Proving a function is functionally complete using it's truth table

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am given a truth table of a function as follows:

\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
            & x & y & z & f  \\ \hline
            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
            & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
            & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
            & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
            & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
            & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
               &
\end{array}

And is asked to prove it is functionally complete/incomplete.
I guess the function is incomplete, because there are an even number of 1's and 0's at the output, and an AND function, for example, has an odd number.

The only property of a function I know is related to the above statement is linearity of a function. Then I can say the function is linear, thus not functionally complete. But the function is not linear, because for every 1 or 0 at the output, the number of 1's and 0's at the input is sometimes odd and sometimes even. Is there any other property of a function I can use for this function to prove it is functionally incomplete?

Thanks.

Comment: I never heard of "functionally complete" in the context of boolean expressions. Please give a definition.

Comment: A functionally complete boolean function is a function that can be used to express all the boolean functions. For example, NAND gate is a functionally complete boolean function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness

Comment: Thank you. Is XOR and its negation allowed as well ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, allowed for what?

Comment: Is "NOT (x XOR y)" an allowed expression (which would give the given truth-table) ? Even easier (but probably not allowed) would be "x=y"

Comment: It is allowed, but I am asked to prove I can express all functions with the given function, not to express the given function with other functions. A far I as I am concerned, this function is a black box, and I need to build all functions with instances of this box only (or to prove it is impossible).

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: I would suggest you start by thinking about what unary (one-input) functions you can make from $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not strictly linear, but  it is *affine* -- in boolean-ring ($\mathbb F_2$) notation it is
$$ f(x,y,z) = 1x+1y+0z+1 $$

It looks like you're confused by the fact that the function ignores its $z$ input so the coefficient is $0$.

Since affine functions are closed under composition, you can't make a non-affine Boolean function such as $x\mathbin{\rm AND}y$.